# Inductive proof for recursive formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, induction, recurrence-relations, exponential-function

So, I have a recursion in which $$a_0 = 5$$ $$a_1 = 1$$ $$a_{n+2} = a_{n+1} + 2a_n$$

I should then prove by induction that the formula $a_n = 2^{n+1} + 3(-1)^n$ works for every number.

Anyway, I generally know how to use induction as proof but doesn't really have a clue on how to use it when it comes to a recursive formula. I have tried to prove the base case but don't really know how to use $k+1$ to my advantage afterwards since I'm not sure how to represent $n = k$ and then that it works for every $n$ by $k + 1$.

Comment: The base case contains two equations here. You can, for example, assume that the equation is correct for $n$ and for $n+1$ and then show that it is correct for $n+2$ as well.

Answer (score 3):

Let's define $f(n)=2^{n+1}+3(-1)^n$. You want to prove that $a_n$, as defined by your recursion, equals $f(n)$.

First, you want to show that $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ give you $a_0$ and $a_1$. That's a straightforward calculation.

Next, you have to show that $f$ satisfies the recursion formula. Does $f(n+2)$ really equal $f(n+1)+2f(n)$? If that works, then you're good.

Consider the statement $P(n)$ to be "$f(n)=a_n$ and $f(n+1)=a_{n+1}$". You've already shown $P(0)$. Checking that $f(n+2)$ satisfies the recursion shows that $P(n)\implies P(n+1)$.

Answer (score 3):

$$a_{n+2}=2^{n+2}+3(-1)^{n+1}+2(2^{n+1}+3(-1)^n)=2^{n+3}+3((-1)^{n+1}+2(-1)^n)=$$
$$=2^{n+3}+3(-1)^{n+2}(-1+2)=2^{n+3}+3(-1)^{n+2}.$$
Now, you need to check that $a_0=5$ and $a_1=1$ by this formula.

Comment: The only way to fly.

Comment: @marty cohen What do you mean?

Comment: Pretty sure that's an idiomatic way of saying you're doing it in the best way, the "only way" worth doing. It comes from an old advertising slogan. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RfmRKHtzfFs

Answer (score 3):

Given $a_{n+2} = a_{n+1} + 2a_n$, and I assume you have done the base case.
Induction hypothesis is : $a_n = 2^{n+1} + 3(-1)^n$

So, let induction hypothesis be true till $n=k$.
Then,

$a_{k+1} = 2^{k+2} + 3(-1)^{k+1} = 2(2^{k+1}) - 3(-1)^{k} $

$=2^{k+1} + 2^{k+1} -3(-1)^{k}=(2^{k+1} + 3(-1)^k) + 2(2^{k} + 3(-1)^{k-1}) $

$ =a_{k} + 2a_{k-1}$

Answer (score 2):

Start with
$a_{n+2} = a_{n+1} + 2a_n$
and substitute
the induction assumption
$a_n = 2^{n+1} + 3(-1)^n
$
for $n$ and $n+1$.

This gives

$\begin{array}\\
a_{n+2} 
&= a_{n+1} + 2a_n\\
&= (2^{n+2} + 3(-1)^{n+1}) + 2(2^{n+1} + 3(-1)^n)\\
&= 2^{n+2} + 3(-1)^{n+1} + 2^{n+2} + 6(-1)^n\\
&= 2^{n+3} + 3(-1)^{n+1}  - 6(-1)^{n+1}\\
&= 2^{n+3} - 3(-1)^{n+1}\\
&= 2^{n+3} + 3(-1)^{n+2}\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore,
if 
$a_n = 2^{n+1} + 3(-1)^n
$
is true
for $n$ and $n+1$,
it is true for $n+2$.
Since it is true for
$0$ and $1$
(by direct calculation),
it is true for all $n$.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need two base cases and you'll need strong induction.  ("strong" means that during the induction step, you assume it is true for all $n \le k$; not just for the single value $n = k$.)

The base cases $n=0; n=1$ are given: $a_0= 2^{0+1}+3(-1)^{0}=2+3 =5; a_1=2^{1+1} + 3(-1)^1 = 2^2 -3 = 4-3 = 1$.

The induction step:  Assume that for all $k \le n$, $a_k = 2^{k+1} + 3(-1)^k$.

Then $a_{k+1} = a_k + 2a_{k-1} =$

$(2^{k+1} + 3(-1)^k) + 2(2^k + 3(-1)^{k+1})$.

You have to prove that:

$(2^{k+1} + 3(-1)^k) + 2(2^k + 3(-1)^{k+1}) = 2^{k+2} + 3(-1)^{k+1}$.

Can you do that?

....

$(2^{k+1} + 3(-1)^k) + 2(2^k + 3(-1)^{k-1})=$

$2^{k+1} +(-1)*3(-1)^{k-1}) + (2^{k+1} + 2*3(-1)^{k-1}) =$

$[2^{k+1} + 2^{k+1}] + [2*3(-1)^{k-1}- 3(-1)^{k-1})]=$

$[2*2^{k+1}]+[-3(-1)^{k-1}]=$

$2^{k+2} + 3(-1)^k$.